# [Python][Scikit] Adapting Spectral Clustering example code (given) to use arbitrary images?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm attempting to modify an example program (given here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_lena_segmentation.html) to use arbitrary image files. Unfortunately everything I've tried thus far hasn't run.

I'm currently trying to use skimage.data.load to load a .bmp file and getting the error "Input must be a 2D array".

I've found that the "lena()" function calls load on a .dat file, and I haven't been successful in figuring out how that image was stored before being converted to a .dat file, so I don't if the issue is .bmp files. Jpegs aren't working either.

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, I'm currently in the process of learning Python.

Answer (score 0):

Lena is a gray-scale image here, meaning it is a 2d array of size `(height, width)`. I'm not sure if `img_to_graph` handles color images the way you want to. Can you give the full traceback?